# Basic question Ruby; why is the total variable not updating in the loop

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

This code is supposed to update the total within the loop, but when I put the total when its broken it doesn't update.

```
total = 0

while true do
  
  puts "Give me a number"
  input = gets.chomp
  
  if input == Integer
    total += input
         
  elsif input == "stop"
    puts total
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: `if input == Integer` this will be false as gets.chomp will give you a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input = gets.chomp` will result `String` class. So your logic on `if input == Integer` it will never be reached. you need to convert it to integer using `to_i` and `input == Integer` i never used that kind of syntax to check the classes, i rather use `input.is_a?(String)`. but if you convert to integer first it will never check `stop` string condition. so maybe

```ruby
total = 0

while true do
  
  puts "Give me a number"
  input = gets.chomp

  if input == "stop"
   puts total
   break
  end

  total += input.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above comment by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) and dedypuji's answer you have a couple of issue.  Here is another variation that I think will work and I think is a little more ruby idiomatic.

```
total = 0
loop do
  print "Give me a number: "
  input = gets
  break if /stop|^$/ =~ input
  total += input.to_i 
 end
 puts total
```